# Vuex unknown action type: getProducts

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to display a list of products by using an Axios API with Vuex.

I created and installed Vuex, in the store directory I created `index.js` and `actions.js`, `mutations.js`, `getters.js`, and `state.js`.

In my Vue.js component when I call the action with dispatch, I get this error:

> [vuex] unknown action type: getProducts

---

Here's my code:

Productlist.vue component:

```html
<template>
<div class="d-flex align-items-stretch flex-wrap">
    <ProductCard v-for="product in products" :key="product.id" :product="product"/>  
</div>
</template>
<script>
import ProductCard from './ProductCard.vue'
export default {
   components: {
        ProductCard
    },
    computed: {
        products() {
            console.log(this.$store.state.products)
            return this.$store.state.products
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.$store.dispatch('getProducts');
    }
}
</script>
<style lang="">
</style>
```

my store (index.js):

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex);

import state from './state';
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations'
import actions from './actions'

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions,   

});
```

state.js:

```js
export default{
    products: []
}
```

actions.js:

```js
import axios from "axios";
const getProducts = ({ commit }) => {
    alert('okkk')
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products')
    .then(response => {
        console.log ('data is', response.dat )
        commit('SET_PRODUCTS', response.data);
    })
}

export default getProducts
```

mutations.js:

```js
const SET_PRODUCTS = (state, products) => {
    state.products = products;
}
export default SET_PRODUCTS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getProducts` is default export, there is no way for Vuex to recognize it under `getProducts` name. There is no way to have more than one action here.

It should be:

```
import * as actions from './actions'
```

and

```
export const getProducts = ...
```

The same applies to mutations and getters.